# Join the link to download a pdf file view and url in Django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I need to associate a link such as "Protocol" and then drive to download a PDF file. Is giving 404 error in mapping the url and would like some help regarding view.

url-Protocol:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('suap.views',(r'^manuais/$', 'manuais'),
                       (r'^static/manuais/manual_protocolo.pdf$', 'manual_pdf'))
```

view-Protocol:

```
def manual_pdf(request):
    response = HttpResponse(extension='.pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="manual_protocolo.pdf"' %manual_protocolo
    return response
```

Comment: Can you post the link you are trying to access? Furthermore your string formatting misses the string which should be formatted...

Comment: I want to access the file to download is inside the folder of the app itself

Comment: There are two options for you: 1. Serving the file via Django (like you are trying a think), 2. Serving the file via the webserver with 2 possible scenarios: a) configure a mapping to your app path, b) use mod x_sendfile to deliver the file. The 404 you get indicates that your view is not called correctly... wihtout more information from your side, I am not able to help more...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use mod x_sendfile in your server. [see](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=mod%20x%20sendfile&oq=mod%20x%20sendfile&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1821j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

also make a small modification to the code

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str('manual_protocolo.pdf')
response['X-Sendfile'] = "/path/to/manual_protocolo.pdf"
return response
```